# @Cacheable not caching Grails POGO method

Tags: grails

I've got a strange issue when trying to cache a method call on a 'repository' object in Grails (2.1.5). This repository, a plain groovy object in src/groovy, combines data from two data sources and returns a 'Seller' object.

```
def aDatabaseHelper
def bDatabaseHelper

@Cacheable('seller_do_get')
public Seller get(id){
    ....
    //do stuff with aDatabaseHelper and bDatabaseHelper
    return seller
}
```

The SellerRepository is defined in resources.groovy

```
aDatabaseHelper (ADatabaseHelper ){
    aDataSource = ref("dataSource_a")
}
...

sellerRepository(SellerRepository){
    aDatabaseHelper = aDatabaseHelper 
    bDatabaseHelper = bDatabaseHelper
}
```

And we've got ehcahce plugin (1.0.0) installed and working fine for other objects/methods.

The above for some reason doesn't cache it - it goes inside the get method each time. I created a 'BlaRepository' which takes in the same dependencies and has a getBla(id) method and it is getting cached just fine.

Does someone has a clue what's going on here? Which silly mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should work, but could be a bug. Create a small test app that demonstrates the problem and run `grails bug-report` and attach it to a JIRA at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE and I'll take a look.